# Xamarin Forms Project builds with errors

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm using VS2015 and the latest version of Xamarin.  I'm trying to build a blank Xamarin Forms project, but when I go to just build the project, I get this error:

> Download failed. Please download 
>   https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/android_m2repository_r22.zip
>   and put it to the
>   C:\Users\warrenbr\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Android.Support.Design\23.0.1.3
>   directory.
>
> XamarinForms.Droid

So I've downloaded the zip and extracted it into the directory, tried to rebuild the project, but no dice. Is there a certain way I have to extract it, or certain folders I have to pull out of the zip?

Comment: Download and put zip in "C:\Users\warrenbr\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Android.Support.Design\23.0.1.3" 
don't extract.
Or extract in "C:\Users\warrenbr\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Android.Support.Design\23.0.1.3\content" folder

Comment: you should add Android support Library from xamarin component section .

Comment: @AlirezaSoleimaniAsl What do you mean by "Xamarin section" ?

Comment: @MiladFaridnia right-click on your android project and you see component. you can add xamarin component to the current project. so simple

Comment: @Brad, Please see my answer on http://stackoverflow.com/a/40083996/1616738 It will help you.

Answer (score 0):

OK, so I had to unzip the contents of the zip into a content folder for each package:

C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Android.Support.Design\23.0.1.3\content
C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Android.Support.Design.v4\23.0.1.3\content

etc...

Then I ended up restarting Windows, and that seemed to do the trick. Rebuilding the solution didn't seem to fix it before this.

Comment: my comment is correct? so that I put it as the answer

Answer (score 0):

You need to delete all from the path: C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Xamarin Folders and Zip files. And then rebuild your project.