# Xamarin support libraries version confusion

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I'm trying to build a project using Navigation View that relies on Support v4 and v7 and Design, I already installed v23.0.1 and I also installed Android Support Repository v30 from SDK Manager which seems to have plenty of older version named folders, everything works perfectly in Android Studio, I use Navigation Drawer with no problem, but with Xamarin I get this error:

`Error      Please install package: 'Xamarin.Android.Support.Design' available in SDK installer. Android resource directory C:\Users\Cayl\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Android.Support.Design\22.2.0\embedded\./ doesn't exist.`

And also this:
`Error Unzipping failed. Please download https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/android_m2repository_r15.zip and extract it to the C:\Users\Cayl\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Android.Support.Design\22.2.0\content directory.`

I'm lost now, why can't Xamarin use the same Support Libraries that Android Studio uses, and why does it require it's own path? help.

Answer (score 1):

This is a known [bug](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/17349/compilation-error-unzipping-failed-please-download-https-dl-since-xamarin-studio-v5-0-upgrade). You should be able to fix it by either following the instructions in the console:

> ```
> Error Unzipping failed. Please download https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/android_m2repository_r15.zip
> ```
>
> and extract it to the
>   C:\Users\Cayl\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Android.Support.Design\22.2.0\content
>   directory

Or by deleting the folder:

> C:\Users\Cayl\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Android.Support.Design\22.2.0

Comment: I tried to install them fro Nuget and now the error wants `android_m2repository_r29.zip` I'm really confused, can I somehow use m2repository v30 that I downloaded from SDK Manager? And when is this bug gonna get fixed?

Comment: @JonneyShih you cannot use release 30 or 31. Check my answer.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be a hard coded binding to release 29 of Android Support Repository and Xamarin.Android automatically attempts to download that with a huge rate of corruption.

More info can be found in

https://blog.lextudio.com/2016/05/android-support-repository-and-xamarin-android/

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting the C:/Users/User/AppData/Local/Xamarin folder, and then clean and rebuild the app.

Answer (score 0):

I have one solution for you: Please download https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/android_m2repository_r15.zip and place it in the ~/.local/share/Xamarin/zips folder and rename the file to match one of the hashed zip file name.

You can also follow step from below link, this will help you.
https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/troubleshooting/resolving-library-installation-errors/

Comment: Thanks I got the drill by now, it all depends on the version of support library extensions that I download from Nuget, for instance version 23.4.0 extensions require `android_m2repository_r32.zip`

Unfortunately none mentions this so I have to figure that out by trial and error.